Lit faces always rendering in front up in front JavaFX
I'm making a simple 3d viewer/editor app, and the renderer for some reason always renders the lit sides on top and unlit ones in the back. here is the full project
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/157aE8AbMWSAd4yxqfAUlN8dMa2Z_67kI?usp=sharing
the bug itself
video of the bug
as you can see the faces are wrong here, normals are not flipped, i checked, im not sure that the bug is in rendering method, so i sent the whole project if needed. i need it to render properly.
again im not sure where the bug occurs exactly so i ask for help
private static void renderLighting(GraphicsContext graphicsContext, List<Point2f> resultPoints, List<Vector3f> worldVertices, Model mesh) {
        // Improved diffuse lighting with soft shadow calculation
        Vector3f lightPosition = new Vector3f(10, 10, 10); // Example light position
        Color lightColor = Color.WHITE;
        Color objectColor = Color.LIGHTGRAY;

        Vector3f polygonNormal = calculatePolygonNormal(worldVertices);

        Vector3f lightDirection = new Vector3f(
                lightPosition.x - worldVertices.get(0).x,
                lightPosition.y - worldVertices.get(0).y,
                lightPosition.z - worldVertices.get(0).z
        );
        lightDirection.normalize();

        float diffuseIntensity = Math.max(0, polygonNormal.dotProduct(lightDirection));

        // Adding soft shadow effect
        float shadowFactor = calculateSoftShadowFactor(worldVertices, lightPosition);
        diffuseIntensity *= shadowFactor;

        double red = objectColor.getRed() * (lightColor.getRed() * diffuseIntensity);
        double green = objectColor.getGreen() * (lightColor.getGreen() * diffuseIntensity);
        double blue = objectColor.getBlue() * (lightColor.getBlue() * diffuseIntensity);

        graphicsContext.setFill(Color.color(clamp(red), clamp(green), clamp(blue)));

        double[] xPoints = resultPoints.stream().mapToDouble(p -> p.x).toArray();
        double[] yPoints = resultPoints.stream().mapToDouble(p -> p.y).toArray();

        graphicsContext.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, resultPoints.size());
    }


Could the face normals be inverted?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
